# При компиляции вывести версию библиотеки

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

Есть проект, который подключает стороннюю библиотеку в виде lib-файла. В этой библиотеке есть две функции

```c
const char * Version();
const char * Build();
```

Вопрос: а нельзя ли как-то при компиляции в лог компилятора в IDE вывести строку

```
printf("%s.%s", Version(), Build());
```

Компиляция происходит в Visual Studio

Comment: Вы можете создать маленькое приложение, которые прям в процессе и запустить.

Comment: @KoVadim как вариант. Но можно нарваться, что приложение и исходный проект будут собраны с разными версиями библиотеки. Библиотека периодически обновляется. Какой-нибудь #pragma нет на этот случай?

Comment: Так это маленькое приложение должно быть частью проекта и каждый раз пересобираться. Оно по факту будет микроскопическое. И проблем с разбегом версий не будет. Если внутри Version/Build просто содержат define, то можно через `#pragma message ( "...." )`  (студия) / `#warning "..."` для gcc.

Comment: @KoVadim я не знаю реализации функций Version/Build. Исходников у меня нет

Comment: тогда пишите по первому принципу. Представьте себе, что это такой себе юниттест. И все станет на свои места

Answer (score 0):

В лог компилятора msvc невозможно вывести результат вызова функции, лишь строковый литерал или результат раскрытия макроса, им являющийся, с помощью [#pragma message](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/preprocessor/message?view=msvc-160):

```cpp
#define VERSION "0.15"
#pragma message("Message version " VERSION)
```

Comment: я так понимаю, Вы комментарии не очень внимательно читали :)